# htaccess redirect if parameter exists not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, get

I'm trying to rewrite any URL if a special parameter exists.

So that this happens:

From: `www.example.com/somepage/someother/?entryValue=somevalue`

To:   `www.example.com/somepage/someother/?product=test&special=12345ls&linkSource=website`

I tried to following, but it doesnt work as expected:
This code adds `var/www/*` instead of the link
`www.example.com/var/www/web6/htdocs/example.com/index.php/*`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)entryValue=somevalue
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/?product=test&special=12345ls&linkSource=website [L,R]
```

This code removes the path:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)entryValue=somevalue
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?product=test&special=12345ls&linkSource=website [L,R]
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do mention more clearly from which url to which url you want to redirect?

Comment: The URL should stay the same, just the get parameter should change, if the URL has the parameter (entryValue=somevalue). The page should then reload with the new parameter.

Comment: Could you please do mention in form of: FROM `http://localhost:/test/etc/test` TO `http://localhost/someting else here..` like this so that we better understand it, because urls which you mentioned in your question not looking much clear, thank you.

Comment: I want this: 
If this link will opend without a get var, nothing happens:
http://localhost:/test/etc/test

But if the link contains: 
http://localhost:/test/etc/test?entryValue=somevalue

The get var should change into this: 
http://localhost:/test/etc/test?product=test&special=12345ls&linkSource=website

Comment: You mean you are hitting link `www.example.com/somepage/someother` which needs to be redirected to `localhost:/test/etc/test` url? Please do mention in this form to clarify requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The complete domain incl. url path should be the same, only the get parameter should be changed, if it is added to any url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)entryValue=somevalue
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/?product=test&special=12345ls&linkSource=website [L,R]
> ```

You need to include a slash prefix at the start of the *substitution* string. Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/?product=test&special=12345ls&linkSource=website [L,R]
```

Without the slash prefix (the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not include a slash prefix) it is seen as *relative* and the directory-prefix (ie. `/var/www/...`) will be added back and result in the malformed redirect you are seeing.

**UPDATE:**

> but this ends up with "index.php" and the path is lost

You've put the directive in the wrong place and have a *conflict*. The order of the mod_rewrite directives is important.

Generally, external redirects like this need to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, before any internal rewrites (like a front-controller).

Comment: Thanks, but this ends up with "index.php" and the path is lost

Comment: @WimDiesel You have a conflict with other directives. Please include your complete `.htaccess` file in your question, with this rule in place.

Comment: Thats it !!!  Your right, many thanks. Ive put it to another part of the htaccess and now it works. Thanks a lot to all.

Comment: @WimDiesel Redirects like this need to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, before the front-controller.

Comment: @WimDiesel You're welcome. Please consider upvoting answers you find helpful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)